# In SikuliX, type(variable) always types the variable then presses enter automatically. How do I avoid pressing enter?

Tags: python, automation, sikuli, sikuli-script

Sorry if this is really basic, I cannot find a workaround. I have a variable called `doc` that stores the number 510 that was copied from an excel cell.

I need to type it in a field, but I need to continue typing in another field on the same page afterwards.

My code has:

```
type(doc)
```

The log shows:

```
[log] TYPE "510#ENTER."
```

The full code looks like this:

```
type(doc)
wait(1)
type(Key.DOWN)
type(Key.BACKSPACE+Key.BACKSPACE+Key.BACKSPACE+Key.BACKSPACE)
wait(1)
type(code)
```

However, I can't get to the `type(code)` because it switches page before I get there...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `paste()` maybe solved your issue here but this is not the right way to do that as Sikuli does not automatically presses any buttons.

Your problem is probably with the `doc` variable itself.  In your case, you probably just copied the new line character with your variable from excel and that's why Sikuli is hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd>. To avoid that, try stripping the new line from your variable prior to typing it, like this:

```
doc.rstrip()
```

Then do your usual `type(doc)` and it should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing that works is: `doc.strip()`

It turns out sikuli writes /n after strings, so strip removes that /n.